# Does this heap snapshot retainer hierarchy indicate a leak?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, material-ui

I'm looking at a Heap snapshot, and I see a retainer hierarchy like the following:

[image]

Does this mean that `MuiThemeProviderOld` (from the `@material-ui/core` lib, highlighted in yellow) is leaking my `gui` instance that you see at the top of the screenshot?

Or what may it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. We inject some dependencies in the global namespace. However we have no idea when you unmount the last material-ui component. WeakMaps would be a solution but these don't work in IE 11. Do you know of any other solutions for dependency injection across npm packages?

However this looks like 400MB of memory? That doesn't look like code only. Do you have a repro?

This is a one-time leak if you don't use material-ui for every part of your app. But it will not increase memory consumption with every switch between routes that use material-ui and the ones that do not.

This will be removed in v4. It is only a temporary workaround.

Comment: I'm loading map tiles that contain LIDAR point clouds with millions of points into a 3D WebGL application, so that would explain the large retained size. I bet that'll go away once I solve the leak. About WeakMaps, I'm in Chrome, so shouldn't there be no problem there? The core-js WeakMap polyfill does not leak and works in IE11. About knowing when we unmount a material-ui component, can't you track that in `componentWillUnmount` of the component, or of the `withStyles` HOC?

Comment: Sidenote about the core-js WeakMap polyfill: it creates a random UUID, then sets the value to be stored on the object itself with the UUID key associated with the polyfilled WeakMap instance and makes the key non-enumerable. Then when the object is GC'd, it takes the WeakMap content with it (because the content is stored on the object itself, not in the "WeakMap" object, so it can be collected).

Comment: Here's the breadcrumb to follow to see no-leak polyfill: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.weak-map.js ---> https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/internal-state.js ---> https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/shared-key.js and https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/hide.js

Comment: I would need to see the code. If you're not navigation away with some routes from material-ui code then my original statement has nothing to do with it. I'm not sure why you think I said WeakMap is leaky? I said it **would** be a solution to that specific problem **I** described. But this is not connected to yours.

Comment: I misunderstood. I do see a "WeakMap" there in the retainer list, which eventually retains the knownClassComponents, but as you can see knownClassComponents is not highlighted yellow therefore no references to it from JS, so because it is in a WeakMap which is also not highlighted yellow, shouldn't the whole WeakMap be collected (and everything it retains)? Maybe I'm not 100% positive I know how to read the info in that screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the code ATM (I'd need to get permission).

Comment: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1180 Is it more of a react-hot-loader problem?

Comment: Thanks for the issue link. Can't really help you with that. Leaks are almost impossible to catch without the code.